# How can I use a gridview inside a column?

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout, flutter-column

I have a column with a container that acts as a header and a gridview of widgets below.
I want only the gridview to be scrollable and that the header will not move and always be displayed.

This is my code:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 22),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Message("Hello, Guest!", size: 32),
                      Icon(
                        CustomIcons.statistics,
                        color: AppColors.blue,
                        size: 32.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 14),
                  Message("What worries you now? Select or Add.", size: 14),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            GridView.count(
              primary: true,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 40.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 40.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              children: _items,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

When it runs I get a renderflex overflowed error:
[image]

When I wrap my gridview in an expanded widget as some answers suggested, the scroll gets out of bounds:
[image]

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

Remove expnaded and wrap your safe area With SingleChildScrollView, and also add phyiscs:ScrollPhysics() in gridview

Comment: But then when I scroll my header container will scroll away and won't be visible any more. This isn't what I want. I want only the grid to be scrollable and for the header to stay in place.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Column with a `SingleChildScrollView`, A Column will always try to shrink-wrap its children, using `Expanded` tells the `GridView` to only take up the available space.

Another alternative is if your `GridView` doesn't grow in too much size is to use the `shrink-wrap: true` and use `physics: const NeverScrollablePhyscis()`, that way the `GridView` won't try to grow to infinite size.

Comment: But then when I scroll my header container will scroll away and won't be visible any more. This isn't what I want. I want only the grid to be scrollable and for the header to stay in place.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `Column` inside a `SingleChildScrollView` widget to make the whole column scrollable. The Code Should be :

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {


const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child:Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24, right: 24),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 22),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Message("Hello, Guest!", size: 32),
                      Icon(
                        CustomIcons.statistics,
                        color: AppColors.blue,
                        size: 32.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 14),
                  Message("What worries you now? Select or Add.", size: 14),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: GridView.count(
              primary: true,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              crossAxisCount: 2,
              crossAxisSpacing: 40.0,
              mainAxisSpacing: 40.0,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              children: _items,
            ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: But then when I scroll my header container will scroll away and won't be visible any more. This isn't what I want. I want only the grid to be scrollable and for the header to stay in place.

Comment: @danieleidlin Okay, then just wrap your gridview inside singlechildscrollview, see the edited answer.

Comment: Didn't work :(
I still get the 'A RenderFlex overflowed by 378 pixels on the bottom.' error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of `Stack`, `ListView` and `Column` widgets. Here's how to do it:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 16),
            ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: [
                GridView.count(
                  primary: true,
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  crossAxisCount: 2,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 40.0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 40.0,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      color: Colors.red,
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      color: Colors.amber,
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      color: Colors.blue,
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      color: Colors.green,
                      height: 200,
                      width: 200,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: 22),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: [
                      Text("Hello, Guest!"),
                      Icon(
                        Icons.ac_unit,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        size: 32.0,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 14),
                  Text("What worries you now? Select or Add."),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: Didn't quite work. The first two containers in the grid were hidden under the header.

Comment: You can solve that by adding a margin or a container with a height equal to the height of the two hidden containers.